# The 2014 Spring GDSE GameJam!

Tags: discussion

The spring gamejam is going to take place here in meta yet again! The jam will take place **12:00 PM Friday the 4th of April to 11:59 AM Monday, the 7th of April UTC time**.

We're going to keep the same rules as before:

> - Participants are allowed to write games for any platform.
> - All publicly available libraries and middleware are allowed.    All publicly available creation tools (e.g. Photoshop or 3DS Max) are
>     allowed.
> - The entrant is allowed use any premade assets as long as    they're freely available on the web and the licenses allow them to be    used
>     in an open source project (e.g. opengameart.org).
> - Assets created by the entrant during the game jam may also be used.
> - The forming of teams is not allowed.
> - Each entrant may ask questions on the main    gamedev.stackexchange site, as long as the questions are on-topic as    per normal site
>     rules. Alternatively, the chatroom may also be used.
> - Each entrant must release their game as open source after attaching a    license of their choice.

The jam's theme will be: *Let's make a game!*

So, think of something nice, and when the jam starts, create it! We figured it would be nice to see what great ideas everyone has, and not bind them with a predefined theme.

Comment: The game jam is now over. You can continue to vote for your favorite entries!

Comment: What a close race! Every downvote counts ;)

Comment: I've secured shirts for each of the winners in this 3-way tie. Congrats to the three winners!

Answer (score 6):

## [Taiketsu!](http://congusbongus.itch.io/taiketsu)

#### A versus shoot-em-up

#### HTML5 ([Phaser 1.1](http://phaser.io))

[image]

- Play online here: http://congusbongus.itch.io/taiketsu
- Source available here: https://github.com/cxong/Taiketsu
- Art from opengameart.org: http://opengameart.org/content/taiketsu-art
- Sound by sfxr: http://www.drpetter.se/project_sfxr.html

I've had this idea to make a versus shmup for a while, and have always wondered how well it could work. There are [very](http://www.shmups.com/reviews/changeairblade/) [few](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WarTech:_Senko_no_Ronde) games of this hybrid genre, and at its core it's fairly simple, so it was perfect for a game jam.

How did it turn out? I guess it's up to you to judge :) I feel that a hallmark of shmups is the finely tuned gameplay, blisteringly hard but not overwhelmingly so. This was impossible for a 2-day jam that relied on PCG :P Still, I'm quite satisfied considering the amount of effort taken. I hope you can enjoy this game for a few minutes.

Comment: Pretty cool. The auto fire makes sense because the player would just be mashing a button shooting 100% of the time because in this sort of game there probably isn't any negative consequences from firing as fast as you can all the time. Would love to see this concept expanded upon further one day. Great work.

Comment: Had much fun. Sometimes I get slow firing ship myself but also slow firing enemy as well. In that case it takes longer to finish the round. I get an impression this game fits more to quick instant gameplay style; quickly going through rounds and rounds. I think this can be worked more into amazing mobile game, more so since it requires no additional input than movement. o_o b!

Comment: Very nice. I like how as parts of your ship get destroyed, you are able to move faster. At the start, it does feel rather useless to move because the bullets move significantly faster than your ship and there's no opportunity to avoid damage. Lots of fun though, :)

Comment: Please ping me in chat to discuss your prize.

Answer (score 6):

## For Sparta!

---

- [**Play Original Version**](http://forsparta-jam.jcpmcdonald.com/)
- [**Play Latest Version**](http://forsparta.jcpmcdonald.com/)  (edited post-jam)
- [**Download for Android**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jcpmcdonald.forsparta) (same as latest version)
- [Source](https://bitbucket.org/jcpmcdonald/for-sparta/src)

---

[image]

---

Take on the role of a lanista in ancient Rome, assembling worthy soldiers that you can fight in the arena.

In the first round of the game, you bid to get your first pick of gladiator. If you drop out of the bidding, you lose half of your investment. If you win the bid, your entire bid is paid for the privilege of selecting the most worthy combatant first. Any money you do not spend in the first round carries over to the second round! So you don't have to spend everything.

In the second round of the game, there are 6 types of tournaments that will be held, each testing your gladiators in different ways. Be sure to check the heading for the competition type (eg: Polearms: Str + Int). Each player selects a combatant, and then the best combatant takes the largest prize, second best takes the second largest prize, etc.

Most money at the end wins!  (Including all money saved during the bidding)

### Notes on Strategy

There are 30 slaves, and 30 prizes which are the same every game, but appear in a random order.

The soldiers' stats are not random, and you will see the same soldiers each game. Memorize (or look at the source) the best soldiers to recognize them when they appear. Note that there is no "best" solider, only soldiers that are most suited to a task.

The six tournaments are:

- **Hand to Hand:** Str * Dex
- **Close Quarters** Str * Int
- **Chariots** Dex * Int
- **Ranged** Str + Dex
- **Polearms** Str + Int
- **Horseback** Dex + Int

Make sure to have a well-rounded troop in order to win each category.

The 30 prizes are numbered 0, 0, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 6, 6, 7, 7, 8, 8, 9, 9, 10, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, and 20.  (So two 0's, two of every number from 2 to 10, then one of every number from 11 to 20).

And the AI does not cheat!

### Credits

Heavily influenced by the card game [For Sale](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/172/for-sale).

Images courtesy of [Terrible Character Portraits](http://opengameart.org/content/60-terrible-character-portraits)

Libraries used: [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com), [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/), [jQuery](http://jquery.com)

Comment: had fun playing. It feels good to be the winner and get all the cash. I wish I could keep the money earned and continue to gamble. Otherwise I feel like there is less point in not using all your money during picking phase; why not just use max bid to get the best warrior. o_ob

Comment: I lost badly :( you mentioned this game was based on a card game? Which one? Seems like it could be a fun party game. If you weren't pressed for time, it would have been interesting to use or even make a Roman name generator - a lost opportunity I think!

Comment: @Tofu_Craving_Redish_BlueDragon, You start with 50gp, and all of the money you do not spend on slaves in the first half carries over into the second half. Most money at the end of the game wins. So, you can get the best gladiator in each bidding round, but you may not make that money back in the tournaments.

Comment: @congusbongus, It is heavily influenced by the game [For Sale](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/172/for-sale). I have just added some notes on strategy to help people not only understand what's going to happen, but how to better prepare themselves to be in a winning position.

Comment: I've emailed you about your prize.

Answer (score 5):

## 2048 CUBE

[image]
[image]

- Play online here : http://kyunghwan.weebly.com/unity.html
- Sound : freesound.org
- Font : http://www.1001freefonts.com/
- Source : https://github.com/kyung01/GDSE_GameJam

I wanted to make a puzzle game that's simple enough for me to finis in time but not too boring-interesting enough for players to spend couple mins playing. Also as it was my first Jam I was afraid of being "lost" in the middle. So I wanted to have a solid model in which I can draw from.

Hehehe. This is certainly not the most original idea,(for those who don't know 2048, [here](http://gabrielecirulli.github.io/2048/) ) but I tried to give it a new spin. I hope it is different enough for you to enjoy.

ps : I set the sound volume very small;

Comment: The sound effects definitely help; I think the camera FOV is a little too high, as it means it's harder to see all the sides of the cube.

Comment: Love it! A twist on a trending addictive game.

Comment: +1 for the twist, did not think this would happen. My only concern is that the first time I played, it did not show the game over message, and the second, it did.

Comment: Please ping me in chat to discuss your prize.